# How do I download an VSTO excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to accomplish the following task.

1. I have an web application through which I will be calling an VSTO apps, I have to insert some values in one of the sheets of the excel workbook
2. I will be inserting the values in the excel sheet and will have to upload to DB using upload button.

What have I done so far.

1. I created a web apps solution. "C:\Examples\WebVSTO\WebVSTO\WebVSTO"
2. I created a VSTO solution. "C:\Examples\VSTO2007\VSTO2007\VSTO2007.xlsx"
3. I insert the values in the excel sheet as below:

   ```
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection objConn = 
       new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(
       "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + 
       @"C:\Examples\VSTO2007\VSTO2007\VSTO2007.xlsx" +
       ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

   objConn.Open();

   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand objCmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();

   objCmd.Connection = objConn;

   objCmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Sheet1$]" + " values ('Test')";

   objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   objConn.Close();
   ```
4. I ran the web application, and observed that the values were inserted in the excel.
5. I upload the values from the excel, by running the VSTO solution and the values got uploaded to the DB.

Issues

1. The excel(only the VSTO excel and not the whole solution) will be placed in a different folder. When I hit the download button in the web apps, the excel will be downloaded in the clients place.

I face the above issue. How do I respond.

Kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question - you're trying to let the user download the Excel file? How have you set up the download and what isn't working? Or is the issue that you can no-longer update the Excel file? You're also using VSTO to modify an Excel spreadsheet from a web application: I'm not sure running VSTO in a server context is actually supported so you may run into issues with that.

Comment: 1. Yes I am going to allow the user download the Excel file. 2. I have not set up the download, the problem lies here. 3. The VSTO application is stored in eg. c:\VSTO.sln, which comprises of three excel sheet (all in one single workbook) and the coding for it. 4. I am supposed to place the workbook in c:\DownloadExcel. 5. The user has to download the excel placed in c:\DownloadExcel.

Comment: Just curious, why do you even need VSTO? If your web app pushes data in a worksheet, and VSTO pushes the worksheet to a DB, why not have your web app work directly with the DB?

Comment: I am going to insert huge rows (around 1 lakh), will send the data through VSTO, around 300 per time. Kept in background worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, The question is quite a generic question: "How do I make a file not on the web application folder available for download?"

The simple way to do it is by writing the binary code into the Response Stream and setting some headers.

```
HttpResponse.Clear();
HttpResponse.BufferOutput = false;
HttpResponse.ContentType = "application/excel";
HttpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=VSTO2007.xlsx");

FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(@"C:\Examples\VSTO2007\VSTO2007\VSTO2007.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
long FileSize;
FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)sourceFile.Length);
sourceFile.Close();

Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
```

I didn't test it but it should work.

Comment: Variant, will I be able to insert the values in worksheet using the above technique

Comment: Not sure what you ment but anyway, this technique provides you with the option to let the user downlaod the file as it is in the harddisk in the moment you open the FileStream to read it. If you close the OleDbConnection before that then the file is updated and will be sent with the new values.

Comment: I went ahead with my way itself , It was such a silly reason, I had not given the ASPNET rights. I had to right click my folder and go to sharing and security tab, and give the right.